# Get fixes values from Ruby Hash

Tags: ruby

I have value response_data which stores this data:

```
{"response_data"=>
  {"transaction_type"=>"void",
   "status"=>"error",
   "unique_id"=>"ec8b1e786efe64f667ad19ff1b39fb92",
   "transaction_id"=>"kcyplptlpk966yifmuct6jj0od",
   "code"=>"410",
   "technical_message"=>"no approved reference transaction found",
   "message"=>"Something went wrong, please contact support!",
   "mode"=>"test",
   "timestamp"=>"2017-11-24T08:07:40Z",
   "descriptor"=>"rwgwg",
   "sent_to_acquirer"=>"false"}}
```

How I can get the keys **status** and **code**? and if they are not found to raise error message.

Comment: Do you know how to get the value for `"response_data"`? Just apply that recursively, two more times.

Comment: @maxpleaner: doing that would invalidate the existing answers there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [default_proc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Hash.html)

> Sets the default proc to be executed on each failed key lookup.

```
class CustomError < StandardError; end

response_data = {
  "transaction_type" => "void",
  # "status" => "error",
  "unique_id" => "ec8b1e786efe64f667ad19ff1b39fb92",
  "transaction_id" => "kcyplptlpk966yifmuct6jj0od",
  # "code" => "410",
  "technical_message" => "no approved reference transaction found",
  "message" => "Something went wrong, please contact support!",
  "mode" => "test",
  "timestamp" => "2017-11-24T08:07:40Z",
  "descriptor" => "rwgwg",
  "sent_to_acquirer" => "false"
}

response_data.default_proc = proc do |hash, key|
  raise CustomError.new('Message') if key.eql?('code') || key.eql?('status')
end

data = {
  'response_data' => response_data
}

data['response_data']['code'] # Custom error will be raised if code is not present
data['response_data']['status'] # Custom error will be raised if status is not present
```

Comment: Your `if key['code'].nil? || key ['status'].nil?` doesn't make sense. Why do you have that there? And what do you think it means? It's `false` only if `key` is something like `"code status"` (a string containing both words).

Comment: @StefanPochmann oh, my bad! Thank you! Now I have written a correct version.

Comment: Ok, the new version makes some sense. But why use `.eql?` instead of `==`? And again, why do you have that there at all? Why not just *always* raise an error there? And you could include the key in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you right you can check if both of `code` and `status` are nil and then raise an error.

```
data = {"response_data"=>
    {"transaction_type"=>"void",
    "status"=>"error",
    "unique_id"=>"ec8b1e786efe64f667ad19ff1b39fb92",
    "transaction_id"=>"kcyplptlpk966yifmuct6jj0od",
    "code"=>"410",
    "technical_message"=>"no approved reference transaction found",
    "message"=>"Something went wrong, please contact support!",
    "mode"=>"test",
    "timestamp"=>"2017-11-24T08:07:40Z",
    descriptor"=>"rwgwg",
    "sent_to_acquirer"=>"false"}}
```

---

```
if data['response_data']['status'].nil? && data['response_data']['code'].nil?
    raise 'Error and code are not found' 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way...

```
status = data["response_data"]["status"] or raise "missing status"
code   = data["response_data"]["code"]   or raise "missing code"
```